# column with values from different tables for each row

Tags: sql, presto

I have a rather complicated problem that I'm not even sure could be done with presto/sql alone; so I'd appreciate any input.

The setup. I have a table of orders... (table1)

```
order_id | customer_id | order_date | blahblahblah....
--------------------------------------------------
 11111   |   5432567   | 2018-12-16 | ..........
 10002   |   6543212   | 2019-01-21 | ..........
 22222   |   3456788   | 2018-11-09 | ..........
```

I have another table (table2),

```
customer_id | customer_rating | as_of_date | 
--------------------------------------------
 5432567    |       A-        | 2019-02-04 | 
 6543212    |       B+        | 2019-02-04 |
```

which updates daily and I must call it with specifying the `as_of_date` , something like this

```
selct * from table2 
where customer_id="6543212" 
and as_of_date='2019-02-04' -- or whatever date
```

Now the problem. I want to create a table, that for each `order_id` in `table1`, picks the `customer_rating` for that `customer_id`, BEFORE the `order_date` in `table1` (e.g. when `as_of_date` = `order_date - 1`), and AFTER the order date (let's say `as_of_date =` today).

To make that slightly clearer, this is my attempt to create a mock table

```
customer_id | order_id | order_date | customer_rating_before | customer_rating_today
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5432567   |  11111   | 2018-12-16 |           A+           |       A-
  6543212   |  10002   | 2019-01-21 |           B+           |       B+
  3456788   |  22222   | 2018-11-09 |           C            |       B
```

Any ideas ?!

Comment: Are you using prestodb or SQL Server?

Comment: None of the as_of_date are after today or did I misunderstand your AFTER requirement?

Comment: Your sample data does not coincide with your stated desired output. You need to provide relevant sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff presto as I mentioned

Comment: @Joakim AFTER the order_date as I mentioned

Comment: @SeanLange the point is that for each row I would have to call the value with a different query.... which is my question...

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean with before and after but  what if there are multiple rows for a customer before and/or after? What is the logic then?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if a customer has multiple orders, the before column would represent the customer rating before each of the orders for the said customer. the after column will always be today, for example.

Comment: But your desired output makes no sense relative to the sample data. I don't think this is really all that difficult but without some realistic data I don't know what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trick.  Bring the two tables together using `union all`.  Then use window functions to get the previous and next rating date on all rows -- using cumulative `min()` and `max()`.

With this information, you can use another window function to get the rating and finally filter the rows to just get the ones originally in `orders`:

```
select ot.*
from (select ot.*,
             max(rating) over (partition by customer_id, prev_rating_date) as prev_rating,
             max(rating) over (partition by customer_id, next_rating_date) as next_rating
      from (select ot.*,
                   max(case when rating is not null then order_date end) over (partition by customer_id order by orderdate asc) as prev_rating_date,
                   min(case when rating is not null then order_date end) over (partition by customer_id order by orderdate desc) as next_rating_date,
            from ((select order_id, customer_id, order_date, NULL as rating
                   from orders
                  ) union all
                  (select NULL, customer_id, as_of_date, rating
                   from table2
                  )
                 ) ot
           ) ot
      ) ot
where rating is null;
```

Comment: this seems like a nice solution,, if it works... I'm trying to figure out what you have done here, reading from inside out. Why do you have the last line `where rating is null` ?

Comment: also, shouldnt it be `select NULL, customer_id, as_of_date, rating from table2` , instead of `NULL as rating` ?

Comment: @A.K. . . . Yes, the rating should be coming into the query.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to organize the combined tables, remove the * and put the column name separately.

Try this

```
SELECT 
    table1.customer_id,
    table1.order_id,
    table1.order_date,
    table1.customer_rating as customer_rating_before
    table2.customer_rating as customer_rating_after
FROM 
    table1, table2
WHERE 
    table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id
```

This combines 2 tables which is old table (table1) and new table(table2)
and it will create two columns of customer_rating from old table(table1) and customer_rating from new table(table2)

Comment: Ummm what??? Also...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: no this is not what I want. I know how to do basic sql. the `customer_rating_before` will need to be called with a different date for each row.... THAT is my question

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged